Mechanism of acid-catalysed intramolecular acylation
A few hours ago, I saw this question on Chemistry Stack Exchange on the ring-forming reaction with polyphosphoric acid and a carboxylic acid. I tried working out the mechanism by myself for the reaction and arrived at this.

The protonation should occur at the carbonyl oxygen instead of the hydroxyl oxygen because of resonance stabilization. The positive formal charge of the oxygen draws the electron pair in the bond toward itself, effectively creating a geminal diol in which the carbon is now positively charged, which is then attacked by the aromatic system to close the ring. Internal proton transfer creates an oxonium ion to relieve the (unstable) geminal diol and the double bond forms, yielding the final product.
Two main clarifications here: is the carbocation step of this mechanism actually feasible? Both oxygens have a positive formal charge and thus higher electronegativities in the molecule. I thought it looks a little weird, but as they are in resonance, would this mean that the 'high electron density' is spread out over the oxygen/carbon/oxygen bonds and so mitigate some of the stress of carbon's positive charge? Secondly: is there something intrinsic about polyphosphoric acid phosphorus pentoxide that plays a part in this reaction to generate the $\ce{R-CO+}$ species? That is: is there an arrow-pushing mechanism that we could draw to  arrive at the $\ce{R-CO+}$ species if indeed it is formed?

I'D honestly go with the $\ce{R-C^+-O}$ intermediate, especially with the $\ce{P4O10}/\ce{H3PO4}$ mix. It would be strange not to get an anhydride as a by product.

The mechanism looks OK to me, except you have failed to include any details of the aromatic subsitution stage of the reaction.

@Martin-マーチン I thought the same. Every reaction I've seen with the polyphosphoric acid conditions results in the production of the corresponding anhydrides. I was just a little confused on how the carbocation intermediate was generated. Many mechanisms I found online, like this answer also on Chem. S.E. seem to require 2 eq. of carboxylic acid to create the anhydride, with no evident R-CO+ intermediate.

Protonate on the hydroxyl oxygen, because its lone pair is sp3 hybridised and so higher in energy than the carbonyl oxygen’s sp2 lone pairs. The higher LUMO makes the hydroxyl oxygen more basic.
Then attack the carbonyl with the pi electrons of the benzene ring and eliminate water through a tetrahedral intermediate. Finish up the mechanism with loss of a proton on the benzene ring as per standard EAS.
It’s debatable whether you loose water or the proton first, but with a barely activated ring, the dehydration is likely more kinetically favourable and happens first.

Thanks for the response. Two clarifications: 1) what is different about this carboxylic acid that leads you to believe the hybridization of oxygen determines protonation, not the usual resonance stabilization that is conferred from protonating at the carbonyl; 2) considering the conditions (polyphosphoric acid), I would expect anhydrides to form too, though in both your mechanism and mine, I see no clear routes to forming this molecule. Is it reasonable to think kicking off the $\text{P}4\text{O}{10}$ happens by the attack of the benzene ring to the carbonyl carbon, where it would be bonded?

@Sonder & Kirandk Hydroxyl isn't more basic, it's just that protonation on carbonyl does nothing. Only when hydroxyl gets protonated it's a productive step.
